# IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using recyclerView and loading data as an arrayList. If the arrayList has less than 7 items, there's no crash.

Otherwise, I have this fatal error:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{3b1755be position=7 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent}

Can anyone help?

**DiagnosticAdapter.java**

```
public class DiagnosticAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DiagnosticAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {
    public static ArrayList<Diagnostic> diagnostics;
    private ArrayList<Diagnostic> mFilteredDiagnosticArray;


    public DiagnosticAdapter(ArrayList<Diagnostic> diagnostics) {
        this.diagnostics = diagnostics;

    }

    @Override
    public DiagnosticAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DiagnosticAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        viewHolder.parameter.setText(diagnostics.get(i).getParameter());
        viewHolder.value.setText(diagnostics.get(i).getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

                String charString = charSequence.toString();

                if (charString.isEmpty()) {

                    mFilteredDiagnosticArray = diagnostics;
                } else {
                    ArrayList<Diagnostic> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (Diagnostic diagnostic : diagnostics) {

                        if (diagnostic.getParameter().toLowerCase().contains(charString) || diagnostic.getValue().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {

                            filteredList.add(diagnostic);
                        }
                    }

                    mFilteredDiagnosticArray = filteredList;

                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mFilteredDiagnosticArray;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                mFilteredDiagnosticArray = (ArrayList<Diagnostic>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return diagnostics.size();
    }

}
```

**ViewHolder.java**

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView parameter, value;
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        parameter = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.parameter);
        value = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.value);
    }
}
```

**Fragment1.java**

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment   {
    private PtrClassicFrameLayout mPtrFrame;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<Diagnostic> data;
    public static DiagnosticAdapter adapter;
    private  OkHttpClient client;
    private  Handler handler;
    public static String constVar;
    private String method;
    public Fragment1() {

    }
    private Boolean mIsRefreshing = false;
    private String ipAddress;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_viewDiag);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new WrapContentLinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        Log.i("mIsRefreshing",mIsRefreshing.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            method = getArguments().getString("method");
            Log.i("METHOD",method);

            loadJSON();

        }else{
        }
    }

    private void loadJSON(){
       // Log.i("Fragment1",ipAddress);
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                //.baseUrl("http://"+ipAddress+":8000")
               .baseUrl("http://10.206.208.92"+":8000")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();


        RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
        Call<JSONResponse> call ;
        switch (method){
            case "identification":
                call = request.getIdentification();
                break;
            case "memory":
                call = request.getMemory();
                break;
            case "sysInfo":
                call = request.getSysInfo();
                break;
            case "conditionalAccess":
                call = request.getConditionalAccess();
                break;
            case "network":
                call = request.getNetwork();
                break;
            case "software":
                call = request.getSoftware();
                break;
            case "loader":
                call = request.getLoader();
                break;
            default:
                call = request.getJSON();
                break;
        }

        call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {
                JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
                switch (method){
                    case "identification":
                        data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getIdentification()));
                        break;
                    case "memory":
                        data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getMemory()));
                        break;
                    case "sysInfo":
                        data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getSysInfo()));
                        break;
                    case "conditionalAccess":
                        data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getConditionalAccess()));
                        break;
                    case "network":
                        data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getNetwork()));
                        break;
                    case "software":
                        data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getSoftware()));
                        break;
                    case "loader":
                        data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getLoader()));
                        break;
                    default:
                        data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getDiagnostics()));
                        break;

                }
                //data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getDiagnostics()));
                //Toast.makeText(getContext(), data.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                adapter = new DiagnosticAdapter(data);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mIsRefreshing = true;
                Log.i("mIsRefreshing",mIsRefreshing.toString());


                //  mPtrFrame.refreshComplete();

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
              //  mPtrFrame.refreshComplete();
                try {
                    adapter.diagnostics.clear();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", "showProgressDialog", e);
            }
                Snackbar.make(getView(), "Unable to fetch json: " + t.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**DemoActivity.java**

```
public class DemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpagerDemo);
        // final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        SmartTabLayout viewPagerTab = (SmartTabLayout)
        findViewById(R.id.viewpagertab);


        TabsAdapter adapter = new TabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new Fragment1(), "memory");
        adapter.addFrag(new Fragment1(), "identification");
        adapter.addFrag(new Fragment1(), "loader");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPagerTab.setViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

**TabsAdapter.java**

```
public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    public TabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
      super(fm);
    }
    public void addFrag(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment, String title){
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      bundle.putString("method", title);
      fragment.setArguments(bundle);

      mFragmentList.add(fragment);
      mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
      return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return mFragmentList.size();
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
      return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the Adapter class implementation.Also please check the way you are initializing the data arralylist. Check if there are any missing index while initializing the arralylist.

Comment: I'm taking a wild guess and say there are also 7 items visible on the activity when you have no crash and they exactly fill your screen?

Comment: @ Totumus Maximus Yes

Comment: Do you modify the content of the adapter anywhere else? Don't forget to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` then.

Comment: @beeb No ,only in the fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using a copy of the data in your adapter?

```
private ArrayList<Diagnostic> diagnostics = new ArrayList<>();
public DiagnosticAdapter(ArrayList<Diagnostic> diagnostics) {
  this.diagnostics.addAll(diagnostics);
}
```

Clear the data like this:

```
public void clearData() {
  this.diagnostics.clear();
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Set new data like this:

```
public void setData(List<Diagnostics> data) {
  clearData();
  this.diagnostics.addAll(data);
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Instead of using `notifyDataSetChanged()` you can use the other notify... functions if you want to use animations or have a better performance.

Hope this works...

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.addAll(java.util.Collection)' on a null object reference

Comment: i fixed this error but i did not understand how to use setData

Comment: I fixed it but i still do not understand how to use setData

Comment: If you have a new list of data, you can use the function `setData()` instead of creating a new adapter. For example you init the adapter with an empty list in createView or whereever. When you get new data from rest service (or whereever) you only have to call `adapter.setData(newlist)` instead of `new Adapter(newlist)` and `recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter)`.

Comment: Thanks, ok i understand now

Comment: Does it need to use `.addAll` in the constructor?