# IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected error while scrolling

Tags: android-recyclerview, androidx

I have a list which is coming from an API which I'm storing in db. Now I'm fetching list from db and showing it in recyclerview. Then removing all data one-by-one from recyclerview listing. This process is being repeated every 10 seconds using JobScheduler. While I'm scrolling, I'm getting this error. I've tried many solutions given in various SO posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461431/indexoutofboundsexception-inconsistency-detected) but it didn't worked.

```js
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionMessageViewHolder{c2276c4 position=31 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent} androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{5223262 VFED..... .F...... 0,0-720,1120 #7f0900d4 app:id/recycler}, adapter:com.sam.testapp.MessageAdapter@4b57ff3, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager@735b4b0, context:com.sam.testapp.MainActivity@e780e56
```

```css
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder> {

    private List<Message> messageList;

    public MessageAdapter(List<Message> messageList) {
        this.messageList = messageList;
    }

    protected static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ConstraintLayout root;
        private TextView umfiTXT, msgTXT;

        MessageViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            root = view.findViewById(R.id.root);
            umfiTXT = view.findViewById(R.id.umfiTXT);
            msgTXT = view.findViewById(R.id.msgTXT);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MessageViewHolder((LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())).inflate(R.layout.row_msg_list, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {
        try {
            holder.umfiTXT.setText("UMFI: " + messageList.get(position).getMessageUMFI());
            holder.msgTXT.setText("Message: " + messageList.get(position).getMessageTxt());
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        try {
            if(messageList.isEmpty())
                return 0;
            else
                return messageList.size();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private void clearData() {
        this.messageList.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setData(List<Message> data) {
        clearData();
        this.messageList.addAll(data);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<Message> messageList;
    private RecyclerView recycler;
    private AppCompatTextView emptyTxt;
    private MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
    private SqliteDatabase database;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        messageList = new ArrayList<>();
        recycler = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        emptyTxt = findViewById(R.id.emptyTxt);
        database = new SqliteDatabase(MainActivity.this);


        recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(messageList);
        recycler.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
        recycler.setItemAnimator(null);

        RxBus.subscribe((Consumer<Object>) o -> {
            if (o instanceof RxEvent) {
                RxEvent data = (RxEvent) o;
                System.out.println("SAM: status: " + data.getStatus());
                if (data.getStatus() == 1) {
                    fetchMessageList();
                }

            }
        });


    }

    private void fetchMessageList(){
        messageList.clear();
        AndroidNetworking.get(Util.url)
                .setPriority(Priority.IMMEDIATE)
                .build()
                .getAsJSONArray(new JSONArrayRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                        try{
                            System.out.println("SAM: fetchMessageList jsonArray: "+jsonArray);
                            ArrayList<Message> templist = new ArrayList<>();
                            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                templist.add(new Message(jsonObject.getString("umfi"), jsonObject.getString("msg_to"), jsonObject.getString("msg_text")));
                            }

                            storeListinDB(templist);

                        }catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError error) {
                        System.out.println("SAM: fetchMessageList onError: "+error.getErrorBody());
                    }
                });
    }

    private void storeListinDB(ArrayList<Message> templist){
        database.insertArrayData(templist);
        showList();
    }

    private void showList(){
        try{
            //recycler.getRecycledViewPool().clear();


            if(messageList.size()>0){
                emptyTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }else{
                emptyTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ArrayList<Message> templist = new ArrayList<>();
                templist = database.fetchMessageList();
                messageAdapter.setData(templist);
                System.out.println("SAM: templist size: "+templist.size());
            }
            System.out.println("SAM: messageList size: "+messageList.size());
            //removeAll();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass your `messageList` to the adapter, so the `messageList` in the adapter and in the activity are the same object references. Then, as I understand, somehow method `fetchMessageList` is called, it's where the problem appears. You call `.clear()` on your list and start an asynchronous operation to fetch a new list, to then synchronously post it to your adapter.

The thing is, after you have cleared your list, your adapter keeps the reference to an empty list now, without being notified about the changes. The adapter still "thinks" that your list is the same size as it was before, so when you scroll the `RecyclerView`, it tries to call at least `onBindViewHolder` for new appearing items. But, as the list is empty, it throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You could try to notify the adapter about the changes immediately after calling `messageList.clear()`, but it seems to me that just deleting this clearing will solve the problem.

```
private void fetchMessageList(){
        //messageList.clear(); <- delete this
        AndroidNetworking.get(Util.url)
            ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Deleting that clear() method resolved the error.